# Where is layoutInflater defined in this android app tutorial code?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewbinding

[This Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-1) introduces the concept of *view binding*, with [this section](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-tip-calculator#2) demonstrating how to use it. In this case, the view binding is set up using the following code.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

The explanation for the call to `ActivityMainBinding.inflate()` is as follows:

> This line initializes the binding object which you'll use to access
> Views in the activity_main.xml layout.

What this does not explain is where the variable `layoutInflater` is defined.

When using Android Studio, the code completion suggests that the variable "comes from getLayoutInflater()":

[image: Snippet of Android Studio screenshot showing code completion for layoutInflater]

`getLayoutInflater()` seems to be a method in [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getLayoutInflater()), but this doesn't help me understand what the reference to `layoutInflater` is doing, where it is defined, and how it is in scope at this point of the code. Can someone help me to understand this please?

Comment: layoutInflater will perform `getLayoutInflater()` under the hood. Kotlin generates getters and setters. I am not a 100% sure but I think layoutinflater is a variable in the AppCompatActivity class.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters

Answer (score 2):

**ActivityMainBinding.java** is the generated class by data binding which has a **static** method inflate(). When you pass the **layoutInflater**(it retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance that is already hooked up to the current context) to inflate() it generates the same code under the code as we usually do while inflating the views and it fetches the layout name automatically.

So, the whole method is like

```
 public static ActivityMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }
```

I hope this is what you are looking and sure can help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came at the same question and found **layoutInflater** was declared in **NavigationMenuPresenter.java**.

```
package com.google.android.material.internal;
...

public class NavigationMenuPresenter implements MenuPresenter {
  ...

  LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
  ...
      
  public void initForMenu(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull MenuBuilder menu) {
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    ...
```

In my case, full path to the java script was

> %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.android.material\material\1.7.0\289bbb3a7fea52532f1163487f9469217ee608a9\material-1.7.0-sources.jar!\com\google\android\material\internal\NavigationMenuPresenter.java

Answer (score 0):

After a little digging I found out that the `getLayoutInflater` comes from the `Activity` class. `Activity` class is parent of `androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity` that is parent of `ComponentActivity` that is parent of `FragmentActivity` that is parent of `AppCompatActivity` that is parent of your `Activity` class.